# Parse form using multiparty works if using Postman but not in NodeJS application using request.js

Tags: node.js, http, post, multipartform-data

I want to send files from two NodeJS applications: App1 and App2. App1 sends a file to App2. If I use simple POST and GET all works fine. Problems come when I use multipart to send a file.

With App1 I want to send a JSON file to App2. So, I wrote the API on App2 to listen for POSTs with files:

#### Code used in App2 to receive files:

```
httpServer.post('/file', function (req, res) {
    log.yellow("HTTP file received");
    res.send('Thank you!');
    res.end();
    let form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        log.red(err);
        log.yellow(fields);
        log.cyan(files);
    });
});
```

So, in App1 I use request.js to make HTTP requests. Before write the function that sends data, I test the API of App2 using Postman as follows:

[image: Using Postman]

or: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAvDN.jpg

So I used Postman to generate the code for request.js which results as:

#### Code used in App1 to send the file:

```
function sendFileToCompanyX(path) {
    var fs = require("fs");
    var request = require("request");

    var options = { method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/file',
        headers:
            {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Accept-Encoding, X-GitHub-OTP, X-Requested-With, User-Agent',
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' },
        formData:
            { 'printLogFile':
                    { value: fs.createReadStream("/Users/sahelanthropus/IdeaProjects/ThesisPrototype/ManufacturerApp/logs/data.json"),
                        options:
                            { filename: '/Users/sahelanthropus/IdeaProjects/ThesisPrototype/ManufacturerApp/logs/data.json',
                                contentType: null } } } };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);

        console.log(body);
    });

}
```

So, using Postman I am able to receive the file in App2 and handle it. But, if I use the App1 to send the (same) file the App2 is able to catch the POST but `form.parse(..., cb)` never calls the callback (neither for **err**, **fields** and **files**).

I used Wireshark to compare data send from Postman and App1, they are exactly the same in HTTP element, but I noticed that Postman uses IPv6 and my application packets uses IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

I solved moving the `res.end();` in the right line:

[image]

This is soon explained: Postman by defaul uses **keep alive** option for the connection, my node application instead (maybe somewhere in `request.js`) uses **close**. This causes the impossibility to transfer the entire file in the case of the POST sent from my application.

Now it works.

[image]

Another possible solution: no change the placement of `res.end()` and set the option **Connection: keep alive** in the sender request.